# The animation style Not working with Chrome

Tags: css-animations

animation style working fine with mozilla and changes color after 5sec but when I tried to run same code on chrome then its not taking that effect??

**Style:**

```
.changeColor{
    animation: change 5s step-end both;     
    } 
@keyframes change {
        from { color: red }
        to   { color: #4D4D4D }
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<label class="changeColor">XYZ</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer 10, Firefox, and Opera supports the @keyframes rule and animation property.

Chrome and Safari requires the prefix `-webkit-`.

```
@keyframes myfirst
 {
 from {background: red;}
 to {background: yellow;}
 }

 @-webkit-keyframes myfirst /* Safari and Chrome */
 {
 from {background: red;}
 to {background: yellow;}
 }
```

When the animation is created in the @keyframe, bind it to a selector, otherwise the animation will have no effect.

Bind the animation to a selector by specifying at least these two CSS3 animation properties:

- Specify the name of the animation
- Specify the duration of the animation

Note: Internet Explorer 9, and earlier versions, does not support the @keyframe rule or animation property.

```
div
 {
 animation: myfirst 5s;
 -webkit-animation: myfirst 5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
 }
```